# NameError: name 'self' is not defined at the last block only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Why it tells me "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" when I run this code?
I don't know why it's all fine except the last block (update method) gives me that error anyone can help?

This code is a game that takes in the lenth of the hand and gives you a random letters to create a word from the hand ,when you enter an currect word, the letters used in the word get removed automaticlly till the words

```
import random 

class Hand(object):

    self.hand = {}

    def __init__(self, n):
        '''
        Initialize a Hand.

        n: integer, the size of the hand.
        '''
        assert type(n) == int
        self.HAND_SIZE = n
        self.VOWELS = 'aeiou'
        self.CONSONANTS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'

        # Deal a new hand
        self.dealNewHand()

    def dealNewHand(self):
        '''
        Deals a new hand, and sets the hand attribute to the new hand.
        '''
        # Set self.hand to a new, empty dictionary
        self.hand = {}

        # Build the hand
        numVowels = self.HAND_SIZE // 3

        for i in range(numVowels):
            x = self.VOWELS[random.randrange(0,len(self.VOWELS))]
            self.hand[x] = self.hand.get(x, 0) + 1

        for i in range(numVowels, self.HAND_SIZE):    
            x = self.CONSONANTS[random.randrange(0,len(self.CONSONANTS))]
            self.hand[x] = self.hand.get(x, 0) + 1

    def setDummyHand(self, handString):
        '''
        Allows you to set a dummy hand. Useful for testing your implementation.

        handString: A string of letters you wish to be in the hand. Length of this
        string must be equal to self.HAND_SIZE.

        This method converts sets the hand attribute to a dictionary
        containing the letters of handString.
        '''
        assert len(handString) == self.HAND_SIZE, "Length of handString ({0}) must equal length of HAND_SIZE ({1})".format(len(handString), self.HAND_SIZE)
        self.hand = {}
        for char in handString:
            self.hand[char] = self.hand.get(char, 0) + 1


    def calculateLen(self):
        '''
        Calculate the length of the hand.
        '''
        ans = 0
        for k in self.hand:
            ans += self.hand[k]
        return ans

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        Display a string representation of the hand.
        '''
        output = ''
        hand_keys = sorted(self.hand.keys())
        for letter in hand_keys:
            for j in range(self.hand[letter]):
                output += letter
        return output

    def update(self, word):
        """
        Does not assume that self.hand has all the letters in word.

        Updates the hand: if self.hand does have all the letters to make
        the word, modifies self.hand by using up the letters in the given word.

        Returns True if the word was able to be made with the letter in
        the hand; False otherwise.

        word: string
        returns: Boolean (if the word was or was not made)
        """

        for i in word :
            if self.hand.get(i , 0) == 0 :
                return False
            else :
                self.hand[i] -=1
        return True
```

Comment: I think it's this line: `self.hand = {}` at the top of your class that is the problem. There is no `self` at the point when the class is being defined. This line should be inside your `__init__` method.

Comment: You have `self.hand = {}` in class body.

Comment: `self` is not a Python keyword like the nearly equivalent `this` is in JS. It is a conventional usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's this line:

```
self.hand = {}
```

at the top of your class that is the problem. There is no `self` at the point when the class is being defined. This line should be **inside** your `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, n):
    '''
    Initialize a Hand.

    n: integer, the size of the hand.
    '''
    self.hand = {}
    # ... and the rest
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked well but can you tell me why when i remove the method "update" it works well without defining this line inside my __init__ method
*notice that it's used in some other methods without giving an error

Comment: I would be surprised if the `self.hand = {}` at the top of your class could be successfully executed, whether or not the `update` method was defined.